# Flask App running on AWS EC2 not working properly after setting up SSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, flask, ssl, amazon-ec2

I recently migrated the Flask application I've been working on to an Amazon Web Services EC2 instance, using Nginx, and managed to (seemingly) setup the SSL certificate for my domain properly using Certificate Manager and CloudFront since I'm seeing the little lock icon  on the address bar.

The site is running fine except that my navbar is now gone and when I try to login I get redirected to the instance's Public IPv4 DNS URL instead. Once I get redirected there, the navbar reappears but my SSL certificate is gone (since I'm no longer at the domain name). I've already tried changing the host from the Flask `app.run()` function.

Is there some configuration setting I'm missing? Or is this perhaps something that needs to be done from Flask itself?  Please help, nothing relevant pops up when I try to find solutions.

Comment: I think there might be some issue in your flask code, you maybe redirecting to a hardcoded link or it maybe wrongly configured. If you share your code snippet for that, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a nginx server block for your domain.

Open nginx default configuration file (on Ubuntu and Debian),

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

Find the line,

```
server_name _;
```

And add your domain like this,

```
server_name mydomain.com;
```

Close the file and restart nginx.

If all goes well, you can install SSL with Let's Encrypt.

[Edit]

Thank you for the support [@Sandakelum Kumara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2345574/sandakelum-kumara). Here's the log when doing `nginx -t`:

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2023/04/03 21:55:50 [warn] 55837#55837: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
2023/04/03 21:55:50 [emerg] 55837#55837: cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/<DOMAIN_NAME>/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:8000000D:system library::Permission denied:calling fopen(/etc/letsencrypt/live/<DOMAIN_NAME>/fullchain.pem, r) error:10080002:BIO routines::system lib)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: I did all that and now my site not only does not have an SSL certificate but is completely broken. 

Comment: what does `nginx -t` say? Can you may be post the contents for the file? Remove references to your domain if you do that.

Comment: I added the log in the edit, thank you very much. 

Comment: Looks like a problem with SSL certificate. Check if your /etc/letsencrypt directory has proper permissions. If you need paid help, this this gig, https://vpsfix.us/fiverr/server-help